# Arranging incoming data into a table with certain conditions

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have a sample text file that is basically a java program. My task was to write a program that could read each and every line of the text file and determine whether it is an assignment statement. And if it is an assignment statement then i need to print out the variable names used in that assignment statement. This is the desired output  I need:

```
ASSIGNMENT STATEMENT       LEFT        RIGHT
data=5;                    data
one=data;                  one         data
x=5.6;                     x
test =(x+5.4)+one/x        test        x.one,x
age=3.5;                   age         
number = 0.2*(age-10);     number      age
x=x+num;                   x           x,num
```

The point where I am stuck is the part where I have extract x, one, x and from the 5th row. And also how to prevent the digits from being printed. like in data =5 how do i only print data and skip the 5?

Can someone help?

Comment: The point where I am stuck is the part where I have to extract x, one, x from the 5th row. And also how to prevent the digits from being printed. like in data =5 how do i only print data and skip the 5?

Can someone help?

Comment: Reword this. To me it sounds awkward. "x, one, x from the 5th row". What does this mean? What code do you have so far?

Comment: This is a homework assignment, no? Please edit and post the code you have so far, or at least psuedocode / an abstract algorithm

Comment: @WhyCry I edited it in the first comment I made. Would you mind checking it?

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes sure. So far this is what I have. It is a very long program how do I copy paste the whole code here? So far I have been able to take out the ";" symbol out of the lines and i have been able to arrange the input into a table. I need help with only figuring out how to remove the numbers and the other symbols{"/,(,(,),+,-,*"} from the assignment statement.

Comment: Oh, this sounds like a regex issue. I'd prefer to have someone with a little more experience tell me I'm correct here, but this sounds like a REGEX issue.

Comment: @OP yes, please only post the part of the code concerning extraction... the part you want help with

Comment: for (int t=0;t<tokens.length;t++)
      {
       if(tokens[t].contains(";"))
       {
        int pos = tokens[t].indexOf(";");
        String tem = tokens[t].substring(0,(pos));
        StringBuilder st=new StringBuilder(tem);
        
        outfile.printf("%1$-30s",tem);
       }
       else
       outfile.printf("%1$-30s",tokens[t]);
       
       
      }

Comment: I dont know how to make it look better. I tried cntrl+K but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using regex?

```
String test = "(x+5.4)+one/x";
//regex: [0-9\"\/\,\(\)\+\-\*\.]+
test = test.replaceAll("[0-9\\\"\\/\\,\\(\\)\\+\\-\\*\\.]+",",");
System.out.println(test);
```

Output:

```
,x,one,x
```

You can then replace the first(last) comma if needed using:

`test = test.replaceAll("^,", "").replaceAll(",$", "");`.

**Some explanations:**

1. `^` represents begining of the tested String,
2. `$` represent the end
3. `[characters]+` means that we're looking for a part(`+`) of the string
   containting characters from `[]`.
4. Without `+` it would look for only one character from `[]`.
5. `0-9` means all digits (range from `0` to `9`)
6. You need to add `\` before every special character that is all of those `",'\/()+-*.`
7. In Java you need to add extra `\` before this regex `\`.

You can test/modify it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

**EDIT**
Example from comment:

```
String tem = "(x + 5.4)+ one/x"; 
tem=tem.replaceAll("[0-9\\\"\\/\\,\\(\\)\\+\\-\\*\\.\\s]+",","); //here added \\s, and comma in second param. Without comma all params will be glued together.
tem=tem.replaceAll("^,","").replaceAll(",$",""); //here you had space in second param of first replaceAll. Thats why the output was " xonex" - the space at the beginnig.
System.out.println(tem);
```

Output:

```
x,one,x
```

If added `\s` to regex (it must be `\\s` in `Java`) - its regex for `space`. 
Look out for the case - `\S` means all but `space`.

Also mind the second param of the `replaceAll()` method (`","`). It is the string that you want to be inserted in place of the found regex (first param). So if your params are to be separated by commas you have to use `","` as second param. If you would like to remove something (like in the second part of this example we're removing commas from begining and and) then you put `""` as second param.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you so much. I am now trying to figure out how to remove the excess commas. Once I have that figured out I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an edit to solve the trailing-leading commas.

Comment: This is working. thank you Michal. I am now trying to format my output so that it comes out as a table. It is not aligning perfectly because the replaceAll method is adding spaces

Comment: Glad I could help. But I don't know how would it add spaces. It only replaces given characters with given *replacement*. In the example above the *replacement* is `,` or empty String `""`. So there are no spaces added.

Comment: @Koolkirtzz Let me know if your having some additional problems with this code. If this answer solves your question satisfactorily, you can accept it.

Comment: Schielmaan I still have a small problem. Please look at the following modifications and let me know how to fix it.
String tem = "(x + 5.4)+ one/x";
tem=tem.replaceAll("[0-9\\\"\\/\\,\\(\\)\\+\\-\\*\\.]+","");
tem=tem.replaceAll("^,"," ").replaceAll(",$","");
System.out.println(tem);   the output of this is like this [x   onex]. How would I fix that?

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me. But the problem is for sure, that in your first `replaceAll()` you have `replaceAll("...","")` and it should be `replaceAll("...",",")` if you would like your items to be separated by commas.

Comment: @Koolkirtzz - I've edited my answer so it has your example from comment explained.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to put a whitespace as a delimiter in the [ ] that eliminated all the unnecessary spaces. Then I added a comma after the +. So now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below to parse the assignment statements and print the variable and operands as you mentioned in the table. You can read the file line and by line and parse it as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String code = "test =(x+5.4)+one/x";

    if (code.endsWith(";")) {
        code = code.substring(0, code.length() - 1);
    }
    String variable = code.substring(0, code.indexOf('=') - 1);
    String expression = code.substring(code.indexOf('=') + 1);

    List<String> operands = new ArrayList<String>();

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(expression, "+,-,/,*,(,),%,\",&,|,!,<,>,=,^,~,:,?");
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokens.nextToken();
        if (isNAN(token)) {
            operands.add(token);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("ASSIGNMENT STATEMENT\tLEFT\t\tRIGHT");
    System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t\t%s", code, variable, operands);
}

private static boolean isNAN(String string) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(string.trim());
        return false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //Do Nothing
        return true;
    }
}
```